# generating Excel spreadsheets in perl that reference 3rd party add-in functions

Tags: perl, excel, worksheet-function

I am trying to generate an xls file with Spreadsheet::SimpleExcel that calls a function that is defined in a third party add in (Bloomberg, if it matters).  The underlying WriteExcel package does not let me write this out because it does not know about this add-in function.  I see the giant hash table of built-in functions that the module knows about and could potentially add this function to it, but I don't know the attributes of the function, especially the 'ptg code'.

Is there a way to either determine what the ptg code (I assume this is something like an opcode) of this third-party function, or is there some way to trick the module into letting me write out these functions without it having to know these details? Or some third plan that I haven't thought of?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Spreadsheet::WriteExcelXML](http://search.cpan.org/dist/Spreadsheet-WriteExcelXML/) and [Excel::Writer::XLSX](http://search.cpan.org/dist/Excel-Writer-XLSX/) should be able to generate Excel files with third party functions.

Both modules use the same interface as Spreadsheet::WriteExcel although with fewer features.

Comment: I'll check this out. I recognize that you are the author of WriteExcel, so thanks for the response.

Comment: WriteExcelXML worked.  I had to change SimpleExcel to use WriteExcelXML but it only required s/WriteExcel/WriteExcelXML/g and s/addworksheet/add_worksheet/g

Comment: Could you also try Excel::Writer::XLSX if you get a chance and let me know if it works.

Comment: I'll give it a shot, though I am stuck with Excel 2003 here. I'll try it at home.

Answer (score 2):

I think you need to use Win32::OLE and it's a bit messy. Try:

```
$xls->AddIns->Add( $xll_path );
$xls->RegisterXLL( $xll_file );
```

where $xll_path is the full path to the xll for Bloomberg and $xll_file is just the xll name.